# Error Composer update Kali Linux

Tags: laravel, linux, php7, debian, composer

favor me ayudan con un problema que se me presento, clone un proyecto y al reaizar composer update me arroja el siguiente mensaje 
"PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0"

A que hace referencia ? Se que tengo instalado el php 7.3 y es un proyecto de laravel 5.7 tengo habilitado php apache y mysql

Saludos!